# Изображение не отображается

Tags: java, swing

Почему изображение отображается не сразу, а только после того, как я потяну за окно, то бишь изменю его размер?

```
    public class ImageLoader extends JPanel{
        Image image;

        {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Games/1.gif"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
    public class TestStart {
        public static void main (String[] args){
            JFrame fr = new JFrame("Test");
            fr.setVisible(true);
            fr.setSize(1200, 850);
            fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            ImageLoader il = new ImageLoader();
            fr.add(il);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вызывать `setVisible(true)` после добавления изображения на форму:

```
public class TestStart {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Test");
        fr.setSize(1200, 850);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ImageLoader il = new ImageLoader();
        fr.add(il);

        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```